# Crash :commitEditingStyle -deleteObject is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

A few users of my app are getting a crash with my TableView which uses a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the data source from Core Data. My View controller is a subclass of `CoreDataTableViewController` which contains the standard code for a NSFetchedResultsController in a `UITableViewController`.
The crash report says that the crash happened in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:]` at the line (code is just below) for this reason:

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   -deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    }
}
```

I tried to look for a similar problem but I didn't find anything and it doesn't always happen (never experienced during testing).

Here is the didChangeObject in my `CoreDataTableViewController` class:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is probably because of tableView which is being passed to the method tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] is deallocated. If you are sure that it is not deallocated then I will recommend you to add exception breakpoint to the code and then test it.

Comment: What are you doing with `suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext` exactly? Did you ask users what they were doing when the saw the crash?

Comment: @Wain I just go crash reports from Crashlytics, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you won't see documented, but it's nevertheless sometimes true: This message can in rare circumstances be fired twice. If it is, the second time `indexPath` will be `nil`.

The appropriate way to handle this is to check for `nil` first:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        if (indexPath == nil) return;

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    }
}
```

I have had similar crashes in my delete routines for many months (possibly years?) and could never figure this out. Until one day, I got lucky and it happened while I was deleting rows with the debugger attached. I was able to see that `indexPath` was unexpectedly `nil`, and my array of items was **already** empty.

This means either the event was fired twice in a row, or the OS called it a second time in response to some action by the user *after* they had deleted the last item. I haven't been able to find out which, and I haven't seen it happen again. However, it explains a number of crash reports I've seen.